# Is there a software mouse debouncing solution? (Single click sending multiple click signals)

Tags: mouse

My mouse double clicks on a single click. Yes, I know its because of faulty hardware, however it should be really easy to write something that sets a minimum amount of time in between clicks perhaps one click per 100-200 ms? I really don't want to buy a new mouse, as this one was pretty expensive and I like it a lot. If some one more familiar with linux can tell me how to fix this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Opening the mouse and blowing it (with a camera-cleaning blower, btw ;-)) solved it for me. Have you tried it? You can also try with a contact-cleaner spray.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-doubleclick.html

I do believe you will want to increase the value and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, that is maximum time in between clicks. I need to set the minimum

Comment: Then have you tried lowing the value? I may have misunderstood the question.  Also, you may need to log out for the changes to take effect = I've never tried.

Comment: That alters the acceptable delay between clicks that will be understood by Ubuntu as "double click" rather than 2 separate clicks. At best, this will affect what a second bounced click is interpreted as, but won't stop sending 2 clicks in the first place.